# myfunction for array of input fields

Tags: codeigniter-3

I have an array of input textbox fields and can add more by the add-row button I want to autocomplete on each text box I have put inline `myfunction` but this can work only if there is only one input field. please help me

**Here is my HTML view:**

```html
<tbody>
    <tr id="row">
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="testname" name="testname" onkeyup="myfunction();" placeholder="enter test">
            </input>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="row">
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="testname" name="testname" onkeyup="myfunction();" placeholder="enter test">
            </input>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="row">
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="testname" name="testname" onkeyup="myfunction();" placeholder="enter test">
            </input>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

**Here is my javascript:**

```js
myfunction = function() {
    $("#testname").typeahead({
        source: function(query, process) {
            return $.get("<?php echo base_url('get_testname'); ?>", {
                query: query
            }, function(data) {
                //console.log(data);
                data = $.parseJSON(data);
                return process(data);
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: i have seen that if i add the fields manually in html the autocomplete works in each field but when i add the row dynamically through add-row button this does not work

Answer (score 0):

Of course it will only work on just one input because it only sees one input because all of your inputs has the same **`id`**, try this:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" onkeyup="myfunction(this);">
```

and then in your js function:

```
myfunction = function(input) {
    $(input).typeahead({
        source: function(query, process) {
            return $.get("<?php echo base_url('get_testname'); ?>", {
                query: query
            }, function(data) {
                //console.log(data);
                data = $.parseJSON(data);
                return process(data);
            });
        }
    });
}
```

and by the way generate a unique input name too.

Answer (score 0):

i have searched a lot to get a solution for working of autocomplete on dynamically added input fields but was unsuccessful i was unable to understand discussion for binding of the events. at last i came to a similar thread and was very beautifully answered. This was just applying of autocomplete in addrow button.
Here is my js script for addrow

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $("#addrow").click(function() {
    $("#testTable").append('<tr id="row"><td><input type="text" class="tes_tname" 
 name="testname" placeholder="enter test">'
    +'</input></td>'
    +'<td><input type="text" class="test-price" name="testprice" placeholder="test 
 price"></input></td>'
    +'<td><a href="javascript:void(0);" <button class="btn btn-default remCF" 
 type="button" id="delrow">'
    +'<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></button></i></a></td></tr>');
 $( "input[name='testname']" ).typeahead({
    source:  function (query, process) {
    return $.get("<?php echo base_url('get_testname'); ?>", { query: query }, 
 function (data) {
            //console.log(data);
            data = $.parseJSON(data);
            return process(data);
        });
    }
 });
```

now it is working and i have no need to put inline function.